# How to add custom field in edit user page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add new field in contact info section of edit user profile page.
I am using this code but it is adding new section after account management section but i want add it after email in contact info section.

```
<?php

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'yoursite_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'yoursite_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function yoursite_extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
?>
    <h3><?php _e("User profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="phone"><?php _e("Operational Manager Email"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text"
                       name="operational_email"
                       class="regular-text" 
                       value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'operational_email', $user->ID ) ); ?>"/>
                <br />
                <span class="description">
                    <?php _e("Please enter opertional manager email.">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'yoursite_save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'yoursite_save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function yoursite_save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    $saved = false;
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        update_user_meta(
            $user_id,
            'operational_email', 
            $_POST['operational_email']
        );
        $saved = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i had it done in my theme in recent project but i did it from the filter name 'user_contactmethods'
Read documentation : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/contactmethods

```
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'extra_contact_info' );

function extra_contact_info( $fields ) {
  $fields['email'] = __( 'Operational Manager Email' );
  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this code works but can we change field type to 'email' current field type is text